# Revisão de código: validações de campos, como abstrair corretamente?

Tags: java, funções, algoritmo, revisão-de-código, abstração

Em uma aplicação Java Swing tenho quatro `JTextFields`:

- Tempo **mínimo** de **entrega** de um pedido em minutos
- Tempo **máximo** de **entrega** de um pedido em minutos
- Tempo **mínimo** de **retirada** de um pedido em minutos
- Tempo **máximo** de **retirada** de um pedido em minutos

Os tempos de entrega são relacionados entre si (mínimo deve ser menor que máximo) e o mesmo para os tempos de retirada.

O usuário pode preencher esses campos como quiser, com texto ou números, mas o que tem valor para mim e que eu espero que ele preencha são valores inteiros iguais ou maiores que 0 (zero) ou então nulo/vazio (não posso usar o `JSpinner` para isso porque este não aceita valores nulos/vazios, somente números inteiros; campo vazio ele trata como zero).

Após preencher os campos, o usuário pressiona um botão "Salvar" que salva os valores caso eles estejam válidos ou exibe uma mensagem de erro se algum deles estiver inválido (isto é, se for não-inteiro ou menor que zero). Existem também as validações adicionais de que os campos mínimos devem ser menores que os máximos.

Passei algumas horas com esse código e custaram a sair as abstrações necessárias. Queria entender melhor como devo raciocinar para chegar a essas abstrações mais rapidamente. Não estou sabendo quebrar os requisitos em funções menores, que façam pouco.

Idealizei um algoritmo a executar quando o botão "Salvar" for pressionado, mas a implementação terminou por não obedecê-lo à risca, e também não saiu com a divisão em métodos que eu esperava. O algoritmo foi esse:

- Verificar se valor é nulo/vazio. Se for, a validação terminou. Senão, segue para próxima validação.
- Tentar parsear valor como número inteiro. Se não conseguir parsear, exibir uma mensagem de erro, senão ir para próxima validação.
- Se o valor parseado for menor que zero, exibir uma mensagem de erro, senão pode ir para a próxima validação.
- Valida se o tempo de entrega mínimo é menor que o máximo, se não for, exibe mensagem de erro. Se for, passa para a próxima validação.
- Valida o tempo de retirada mínimo é menor que o máximo, se não for, exibe mensagem de erro. Se for, as validações passaram e a aplicação pode seguir com o salvamento.

Parece simples e parece até que o algoritmo está pronto para implementar, mas não consegui decidir as assinaturas dos métodos e o nível de abstração a que deveriam pertencer. Acabei levando uma "surra" do código por algumas horas. Poderia até tentar resolver de qualquer jeito, mas estou tentando ser particularmente rigoroso com essa parte do código, até mesmo para aprendizado.

Queria entender qual linha de raciocínio devo seguir para transformar esses requisitos em código manutenível e com boa abstração. Uma das minhas dúvidas é se o princípio [CQS (Command-Query Separation)](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) deve ser respeitado ou não. No meu caso considerei que ele estava atrapalhando e o ignorei.

```
private static final int DELIVERY_AND_COUNTER_MINIMUM_TIME = 0;

private JTextField textFieldTempoDeEntregaMin;
private JTextField textFieldTempoDeEntregaMax;
private JTextField textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMin;
private JTextField textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMax;

private void jButtonSalvarActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    trimTextField(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMin);
    trimTextField(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMax);
    trimTextField(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMin);
    trimTextField(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMax);

    if (false == validateTime(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMin, "Tempo de entrega mínimo") ||
        false == validateTime(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMax, "Tempo de entrega máximo") ||
        false == validateTime(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMin, "Tempo de retirada mínimo") ||
        false == validateTime(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMax, "Tempo de retirada máximo")) {
        return;
    }

    if (false == isSmallerThan(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMin, textFieldTempoDeEntregaMax)) {
        showMessage("Tempo mínimo de entrega não pode ser maior ou igual que máximo.");
        return;
    }

    if (false == isSmallerThan(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMin, textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMax)) {
        showMessage("Tempo mínimo de retirada não pode ser maior ou igual que máximo.");
        return;
    }

    Integer minDeliveryTimeInMinutes = parseValidTime(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMin.getText());
    Integer maxDeliveryTimeInMinutes = parseValidTime(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMax.getText());
    Integer minCounterTimeInMinutes = parseValidTime(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMin.getText());
    Integer maxCounterTimeInMinutes = parseValidTime(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMax.getText());

    DeliveryAndCounterTimes timesToChange = new DeliveryAndCounterTimes(minDeliveryTimeInMinutes,
            maxDeliveryTimeInMinutes, minCounterTimeInMinutes, maxCounterTimeInMinutes);

    // Efetua o salvamento.
}

private void trimTextField(JTextField textField) {
    textField.setText(textField.getText().trim());
}

private boolean validateTime(JTextField textField, String fieldName) {
    String text = textField.getText();
    if (isNotEmptyNorParsableToInteger(text)) {
        showMessage(fieldName + ": valor inválido (não é um número inteiro).");
        return false;
    } else if (isParsableToNegative(text)) {
        showMessage(fieldName + ": valor inválido (menor que zero).");
        return false;
    }

    // Is either empty or parsable to non-negative
    return true;
}

private boolean isParsableToNegative(String text) {
    return IntegerUtils.isParsable(text) && Integer.parseInt(text) < DELIVERY_AND_COUNTER_MINIMUM_TIME;
}

private boolean isNotEmptyNorParsableToInteger(String text) {
    return text != null && false == text.trim().isEmpty() && false == IntegerUtils.isParsable(text);
}

private void showMessage(String message) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message);
}

private boolean isSmallerThan(JTextField textFieldMinimum, JTextField textFieldMaximum) {
    String textMinimum = textFieldMinimum.getText();
    String textMaximum = textFieldMaximum.getText();
    Integer minimum = parseValidTime(textMinimum);
    Integer maximum = parseValidTime(textMaximum);

    return (minimum != null && maximum != null && minimum < maximum);
}

private Integer parseValidTime(String validTime) {
    if (IntegerUtils.isParsable(validTime)) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(validTime) < DELIVERY_AND_COUNTER_MINIMUM_TIME) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Tempo negativo: " + validTime);
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(validTime);
    } else if (validTime != null && false == validTime.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Tempo inválido: " + validTime);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**IntegerUtils.java:**

```
public class IntegerUtils {

    public static boolean isParsable(String input) {
        boolean parsable = true;
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            parsable = false;
        }
        return parsable;
    }
}
```

Creio que este tamanho de código é ideal para uma revisão de código sem a pergunta ficar ampla demais. Mas revisão de código não é bem o que quero; procuro formas de quebrar os requisitos em funções de forma que a quebra fique próxima desse resultado sem demorar tanto em outros raciocínios de código que acabaram sendo jogados fora.

Observando o código desenvolvido, há dois momentos que considero chaves:

- Quando foi decidido ignorar o CQS. Com isso foi possível exibir as mensagens de erro como efeito colateral de alguns métodos.
- Quando foi decidido lidar somente com campos não-parseados válidos de acordo com a regra de negócio. Com isso o desenvolvimento se dividiu em duas etapas: antes e depois de validar os campos.

Outros momentos podem ser percebidos, mas com influência menor. Me pergunto se há uma linha de raciocínio muito específica para o problema em questão ou princípios mais genéricos que possam ser aplicados na hora de tentar quebrar o problema.

De início perdi tempo tentando implementar algo assim:

```
private void jButtonSalvarActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    validateTimes();

    ...

}

private void validateTimes() {
    validateTime(textFieldTempoDeEsperaMin.getText());
    validateTime(textFieldTempoDeEsperaMax.getText());
    validateTime(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMin.getText());
    validateTime(textFieldTempoDeRetiradaMax.getText());
}
```

Algumas constatações que eram necessárias:

- Há quatro campos de texto, então serão quatro validações independentes;
- Para trabalhar corretamente validando de par em par é preciso validar os campos individualmente primeiro;
- Cada validação é independente da outra; não existe semelhança a ser aproveitada, em particular na exibição de mensagens de erro;
- Espere ter um bom panorama do código, para reduzir as duplicações;
- O método `isParsable()` entrou de gaiato na implementação, quando pesquisei no Google sobre o comportamento de parsear strings. É um método interessante e vem a calhar, mas provavelmente não teria pensado nele por conta própria. Em outro cenário o que poderia ter me levado a pensar nele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Nomenclatura

Você usa nomes em Português (`textFieldTempoDeEntregaMin`) e em Inglês (`isSmallerThan`). Isso não é um grande problema, mas deixa o projeto feio. Quando eu dou manutenção em um projeto que mistura estilos de nomenclatura, fico com a impressão de que foi feito "nas coxa".

### Consistência na abstração

Há métodos auxiliares que trabalham com tipos menos específicos, como a `isNotEmptyNorParsableToInteger`, e outros que trabalham com tipos bastante específicos, como `isSmallerThan`. Isso é similar ao code smell chamado [intimidade inapropriada](https://refactoring.guru/smells/inappropriate-intimacy). Opte por trabalhar com tipos menos específicos sempre que possível, isso te permitirá reutilizar esses métodos em vários contextos diferentes.

### Eficiência e Separação de responsabilidades parte 1

Você chama o método `Integer.parseInt` *muitas vezes*. Digamos que o método `parseValidTime` seja chamado com o parâmetro `"42"`:

1. O primeiro condicional chama o método `isParsable`, que, por sua vez, chama o `Integer.parseInt`.
2. O próximo condicional chama diretamente o `Integer.parseInt`.
3. O `return` também chama o `Integer.parseInt`.

Foram 3 chamadas seguidas passando exatamente o mesmo argumento! Você pode melhorar bastante essa lógica. Exemplo:

```java
private static int parsePositiveInt(String strValue) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(strValue);

    if (value < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Perceba que eu removi as referências à palavra "tempo" e a chamada ao `showMessage`. O fato desse método ser usado na validação do tempo de entrega é totalmente irrelevante para o método em si. Agora ele se tornou reutilizável e você pode aplicá-lo em qualquer outro trecho de código que precise converter strings para inteiros positivos. Exemplo de uso:

```java
private void jButtonSalvarActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    int tempoMinimoEntrega;

    try {
        tempoMinimoEntrega = parsePositiveInt(textFieldTempoDeEntregaMin.getText());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        showMessage("O tempo mínimo de entrega deve ser um número inteiro positivo");
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Aliás, o método `parsePositiveInt` não deve ser declarado dentro da controller da tela.

### Arquitetura e Separação de responsabilidades parte 2

Um problema que salta aos olhos é que você misturou bastante as regras de negócio com apresentação de dados. Em projetos javax.Swing é muito comum isso acontecer, infelizmente. Eu te aconselho fortemente a modelar a sua aplicação usando MVC (ou outro padrão similar), exatamente como fazemos em aplicações web. A única diferença, no caso, seria que a view não é um código HTML, mas sim um código Java.

A controller e a view não precisam saber que o tempo mínimo deve ser menor que o tempo máximo. Isso é uma particularidade do seu negócio, não da tela, então isso deve ser feito por uma classe especializada em validar regras de negócio referentes à entrega (por exemplo, uma classe chamada `EntregaService`).

Com essa separação você poderá usar um framework de teste unitário para testar as regras de negócio isoladamente, além de tornar o código menos confuso.

---

### Respondendo perguntas levantadas nos comentários

> "Opte por trabalhar com tipos menos específicos sempre que possível" parece uma boa dica, tenho curiosidade em saber onde/como você a aprendeu

Por experiência própria e porque é algo natural. Hierarquia de classes existe por uma razão: *Abstração*. Imagine se o método `System.out.println` não aceitasse um `Object`, você não poderia usá-lo para printar objetos de classes que você criou. Devido ao fato de todas as classes herdarem de `Object`, esse método aceita qualquer objeto.

> Quanto a chamar um método várias vezes, qual seria o mal nisso?

O maior mal é a perda de performance. Você poderia salvar o resultado do `Integer.parseInt` numa variável e usar a variável em vez de mandar o Java converter a string de novo e de novo.

> em parsePositiveInt() não leva em consideração que um tempo pode ser null e que é melhor que o método não lance exceção (a meu ver um input inválido do usuário não é tão excepcional assim, é quase esperado)

O método `Integer.parseInt` lança `IllegalArgumentException` se o argumento passado for `null`. Isso significa que o `try`-`catch` que eu fiz dentro do `jButtonSalvarActionPerformed` já vai tratar esse caso.

Comment: Desculpe a demora em responder. _"Opte por trabalhar com tipos menos específicos sempre que possível"_ parece uma boa dica, tenho curiosidade em saber onde/como você a aprendeu. Quanto a chamar um método várias vezes, qual seria o mal nisso? Seria indicativo de lógica falha? A sua em `parsePositiveInt()` não leva em consideração que um tempo pode ser `null` e que é melhor que o método não lance exceção (a meu ver um input inválido do usuário não é tão excepcional assim, é quase esperado). Quanto ao MVC desktop, ele é desejável, mas não sei bem por onde começar a aplicá-lo na aplicação.

Comment: Olá, vi que não voltou para responder meu comentário, eu gostaria realmente de pedir desculpas pela demora em comentar sua resposta porque eu tomei um tempo para refletir sobre ela com atenção, pois tinha muito conteúdo bom. Peço desculpas novamente e agradeço por ter tomado tempo para responder minha pergunta.

Comment: @Piovezan Respondi suas perguntas, me avise se quiser que eu expanda alguma explicação.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas. Custou um pouco mas eu entendi a questão dos parâmetros menos específicos; `System.out.println()` é bastante reutilizável, assim também deveriam ser meus métodos. Eu discordo da questão da performance nesse caso em especifico porque a performance do parseamento é irrisória. Quanto à possibilidade de um parâmetro vir `null`, acho que não fui claro, mas o `null` é um valor válido, ele não deveria lançar exceção nesse caso.