# Como dividir um programa em funções?

Tags: funções, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, modularização

Como dividir o código em funções no paradigma imperativo? Depende do tipo (procedural, modular, OOP)? É amplo perguntar isso, mesmo que somente para um desses subparadigmas? Existe algum material de referência? Existem boas prát... digo, recomendações?

#### Recomendações específicas:

- A afirmação abaixo (tirada [daqui](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3314640/functional-programming-for-java-developers-part-1.html)) é verdadeira?

> Backus asserted that the Von Neumann architecture and its associated imperative languages are fundamentally flawed, and presented a functional-level programming language (FP) as a solution.

- É melhor [dividir um programa extenso em funções pequenas](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345344/splitting-up-a-very-large-function-program-into-smaller-functions-effective) para ter mais potencial de reaproveitamento do código? Esse potencial é significativo? Essa última pergunta é sujeita a opiniões?
- Ao criar funções/métodos é melhor [optar por trabalhar com tipos menos específicos sempre que possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/388645/357), a fim de permitir reutilizar essas funções/métodos em vários contextos diferentes?

Comment: Estou analisando se a pergunta tem os problemas que cita, ainda não vi tudo :D O parágrafo final não sei se tem a ver ou só não está claro a relação com o resto. Acho que consigo dar uma resposta, mas daquelas que eu não afirmo categoricamente porque o assunto não é simples, por isso espero não ter respostas ingênuas que citam o conceito popular que pode não ser bem certo. A citação mesmo eu consigo contestar o mérito, não sei se o conteúdo que é mais complicado. O "como dividir" para amplo sim. Entendo a intenção, mas isso lava a algo muito aberto.

Comment: A relação do parágrafo final com o resto no meu entendimento seria que trabalhar com tipos menos específicos afeta o design das funções e portanto a forma de dividir o programa nas mesmas. O que puder salvar na pergunta está valendo.

Comment: Basta seguir o princípio da responda única. Uma função deve fazer uma, e somente uma, coisa bem feita. Tudo o resto é consequência.

Comment: O que eu acho dfiícil nessa pergunta é saber o que é "dividir em funções", porque o corpo tem umas coisas interessantes. Estou pensando em começar responder, mas o problema é que seria quase interativo porque ainda dá confusão. De certa forma a resposta para o título é o que o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse. É vago? É. Por isso muitas vezes eu acho melhor a pessoa mostrar algo e ver se fere o SRP para começar entender isso. E quase cai em opinião pq cada pessoa pode ter um critério diferente. EU questiono uma das fontes que mais fala em SRP no mundo que te obriga escrever código demais por um ideal

Comment: Não tenho exemplos. Concordo que "dividir em funções" é vago, depende de contexto e torna a pergunta ampla, assim como respeitar o SRP é vago. Estou partindo da premissa que dividir em funções seja uma ciência conhecida e vai além de simplesmente "seguir o SRP" (a não ser que esta seja uma regra muito antiga e tradicional), por isso pergunto o que pode haver de material de referência, como por exemplo algo [nessa linha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_analysis_and_design_technique) ou mesmo [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785441/how-to-decompose-a-system-into-modules).

Comment: Não é, esse é o problema, é tão vago qto quase tudo que se ensina em redação. Tirando ortigrafia, gramática, essas coisas mais objetivas, o estilo se dá de forma subjetiva. Tem uma certa objetividade no subjetivo, mas ainda é subjetivo. Você dá linhas gerais que são um pouco vagas. Quando falamos de linguagem estamos falando de expressão, não importa o tipo de linguagem. Tem estilos e estilos. Tem regras gerais para seguir, mas específicas é difícil. Até dá pra fazer uma coleção de exemplos, mas isso é bem amplo. Por isso fazer e perguntar pode ser muito mais específico.

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: Vendo alguns links que postou, fico pensando se o que quer saber é como dividir ou se é outra coisa :) De fato depende do paradigma há critérios diferentes a seguir, mas nada tem a ver com dividir.

Comment: Você pergunta isso por causa do link perguntando como decompor em módulos, certo? Mas isso você já respondeu na minha pergunta sobre programação modular, a dúvida é sobre dividir, quebrar em funções mesmo. E o link sobre SADT se trata da dúvida se há um método a seguir para proceder com essa divisão. Percebo que os links não têm muita coesão, são meio aleatórios, mas a intenção geral é o título da pergunta. Seria como quebrar um módulo em funções, mas acho que isso esbarra em como dividir em módulos. Não sei explicar melhor, falta um exemplo mesmo.

Comment: Na verdade como um módulo pode ser uma função também e como minha maior deficiência é em projetar funções (dividir está sendo usado como sinônimo de projetar, modularizar), a dúvida recai sobre como projetar funções em programação procedural, o que leva a como projetar módulos e um programa completo. Devo estudar Análise Estruturada?