# Critério para decomposição modular

Tags: projeto-de-software, programação-modular

Tirado de: http://wiki.c2.com/?EncapsulationIsNotInformationHiding (ênfase minha):

> As the article linked to at the top of the page mentions, "information hiding" was introduced by DavidParnas in the early 1970's. The best known (but I believe not earliest) paper by him about it is OnDecomposingSystems, where he shows two decompositions of a system for producing a KWIC index. This paper is also referenced by the CodeComplete chapter on modularity. The conclusion of the paper recommends that **"one begins [to decompose a system] with a list of difficult design decisions or design decisions that are likely to change. Each module is then designed to hide such a decision from the others." this is contrasted with the "conventional" decomposition, which is driven by functional decomposition.**
> The two solutions to the KWIC problem are not presented at a high level of detail, but do clearly involve a program built out of "functions or procedures", a module being accessed by the use of some nominated functions that form the interface to the module. The paper is all about improving the use of modular programming.

O artigo do Parnas é muito bem considerado mas também muito árido de se ler. Alguém explica essa abordagem enfatizada na citação que projeta um módulo baseado em uma lista de decisões de design difíceis ou de decisões de design prováveis de sofrer mudança? Como isso se dá na prática?

#### Links adicionais:

[Descrição simplificada do artigo](https://swizec.com/blog/week-16-on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/swizec/6524)

[Conteúdo de um curso](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eouster/cgi-bin/cs190-winter18/lectures.php) na Stanford University sobre design de software que aborda o estudo do artigo (o próprio instrutor tem um [livro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1732102201) sobre design de software, que trata da separação em módulos).

Comment: Adoro esse artigo, alias adoro essa Wiki toda, é uma das coisas mais sensaciocnais que eu já e tenho uma inveja dela. Eu queria fazer algo semelhante em pt, mas sei que não daria certo por falta de capital humano para gerar bons materiais. Claro que só seria interessante ter algo assim para evoluir o que é dito lá. Pensei várias vezes em fazer, mas sempre esbarra nessa limitação. Eu vou pensar, mas não sei se consigo dar uma resposta adequada pra isso "hoje". Pode ser um dia, e esse dia pode ser logo porque pode ter me incentivado estudar mais o assunto.

Comment: O Parnas tem uma visão muito mais adequada de OOP (ainda que eu questione um pouco algumas coisas bem pontuais) mas realmente nem sempre é fácil ler e interpretar. Se a pessoa ler tudo dele com a cabeça limpa pode melhorar muito sua programação e quem sabe falar menos em OOP e mais em modularização :D Eu ainda não sei se é fácil responder essa pergunta, talvez caia no mesmo problema de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408711/101, se não for dup (talvez uma deveria substituir a outra). Verei o que posso fazer.

Comment: "Ler tudo dele", são só mais de 200 artigos :P mas vou me esforçar para ler alguns. Quanto à dup, se precisar apagar uma, sem problemas, eu apago.