# Um caso de design de algoritmo (ou: como dividir um programa em funções, parte 2)

Tags: funções, algoritmo, classificação, projeto-de-software, modularização

Vou apresentar duas implementações de algoritmo, uma melhor e uma pior, compará-las, e a pergunta é a quais pontos devo me atentar para obter uma implementação melhor, mais modular.

O algoritmo de **ordenação por seleção** (*selection sort*) percorre uma lista sucessivas vezes a partir de um índice inicial cada vez maior, fazendo a cada passagem uma troca do menor elemento encontrado com o elemento da posição em que iniciou essa passagem.

Esta implementação feita em Python me intrigou:

```
def selectionSort(listToSort):
    for starting_index in range(len(listToSort)):
        min_elem_index = index_of_min(listToSort, starting_index)
        swap(listToSort, starting_index, min_elem_index)
    return listToSort

def index_of_min(aList, start_index):
    min_elem_index = start_index
    for i in range(start_index, len(aList)):
        if aList[i] < aList[min_elem_index]:
            min_elem_index = i
    return min_elem_index

def swap(aList, i, j):
    temp = aList[i]
    aList[i] = aList[j]
    aList[j] = temp

listToSort = [2, 5, 4]
selectionSort(listToSort)
print (listToSort)

Saída:
>>> [2, 4, 5]
```

Foi proposto que para implementar o algoritmo tudo o que era preciso era uma função `index_of_min(aList, start_index)` e uma função `swap(aList, i, j)`.

Na hora imaginei que nunca teria idealizado o algoritmo assim. Tentei fazer e saiu algo assim, quase num "monólito" só, e incorreto, pois faz *swaps* adicionais desnecessários:

```
def selectionSort(listToSort):
    for i in range(0, len(listToSort)):
        min = listToSort[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(listToSort)):
            if listToSort[j] < min:
                min = listToSort[j]
                swap(listToSort, i, j)
    return listToSort

def swap(list, i, j):
    aux = list[i]
    list[i] = list[j]
    list[j] = aux
```

...que depois evoluiu para uma versão mais correta:

```
def selectionSort(listToSort):
    for i in range(0, len(listToSort)):
        min = listToSort[i]
        posicao_min = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(listToSort)):
            if listToSort[j] < min:
                min = listToSort[j]
                posicao_min = j
        swap(listToSort, i, posicao_min)
    return listToSort
```

Note que nestas tentativas a variável `min` recebeu uma atenção grande logo no início do raciocínio para montar o algoritmo, maior que a variável `posicao_min`. No outro a variável `min_elem_index`, equivalente a esta última, e gerada por `index_of_min()`, recebeu uma atenção maior, e esse resultado foi usado pela função `swap()`.

Acontece que, apesar da implementação da função `swap()` ter ficado parecida (talvez na hora eu nem tivesse chegado a fazê-la, talvez tivesse feito um "inline" de uma na outra), o primeiro design de funções (o que não é meu) é bem melhor que o segundo. Eu queria que me ajudassem a entender por que ele foi feito assim e por que acabou ficando melhor.

Primeiramente, foi um design top-down? Mas ambos foram top-down, a meu ver. No primeiro foi feito um *divide & conquer* ("dividir para conquistar")? No que consistiu ele? Foi extraída dos requisitos, ou definida, uma interface, uma funcionalidade que se desejava que as funções fornecessem?

Em particular, a primeira "sub-função", que é a `index_of_min()`, tem seu retorno aproveitado na segunda. Por que esse design não foi pensado na elaboração da segunda implementação? O que eu deveria ter em mente para haver esse aproveitamento? Um ponto a se pensar é que o algoritmo não estava muito claro para mim na hora de implementar, pois foi posteriormente corrigido.

A segunda implementação trata o `swap` como um passo menor, secundário, adjutório; já a primeira o trata como ponto-chave do algoritmo e em função disso (com o perdão do trocadilho) define quais parâmetros ele deve usar, e com isso o que precisa ser retornado pela função `index_of_min()`.

Isso acabou gerando uma design mais simples e modular, com o código bem distribuído.

Ou, alternativamente, o índice do valor mínimo obtido a cada passagem pela lista foi tratado como elemento-chave no algoritmo e sua obtenção recebeu importância primária por meio de `index_of_min()`.

Como devo proceder, ao projetar código, para ter esse tipo de *insight*?

Era esse tipo de *insight* que eu tenho dificuldade em ter e queria aprender quando perguntei [Como dividir um programa em funções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408711/357) Acho meus designs em geral meio rocambólicos.

A pergunta inversa também é interessante: dado um "rocambole" como esse, como identificar e quebrar adequadamente em módulos?

#### Possível solução

Um tempo depois desta pergunta fiz um exercício de dividir o código em funções pequenas em que cada uma faz uma coisa só, e isso a meu ver produziu um resultado positivo. Não responde totalmente a dúvida sobre o design do algoritmo de ordenação por seleção em si, mas parece ser um caminho a se seguir, para reduzir a carga cognitiva sobre cada função e raciocinar sobre os algoritmos mais corretamente, além de permitir maior reúso do código.

#### Em tempo

<strike>Qual está melhor do ponto de vista da corretude? Não tenho certeza mas numa olhada rápida parece que tem um *bug* em `index_of_min()`, que é estar usando `range(start_index, len(aList))` e não `range(start_index + 1, len(aList))`. Procede?</strike>

Ambos estão incorretos; o *range* de `i` pode variar de `0` a `len(lista) - 1` (indo assim na verdade até `len(lista) - 2`), e a busca pelo índice mínimo pode variar de `start_index + 1` a `len(lista)` (indo assim na verdade até `len(lista) - 1)`.

Seguem versões melhoradas de ambos os algoritmos. Primeiro algoritmo:

```
def selectionSort(aList):
    for starting_index in range(len(aList) - 1):
        min_elem_index = index_of_min(aList, starting_index)
        swap(aList, starting_index, min_elem_index)

def index_of_min(aList, start_index):
    min_elem_index = start_index
    for i in range(start_index + 1, len(aList)):
        if aList[i] < aList[min_elem_index]:
            min_elem_index = i
    return min_elem_index

def swap(aList, i, j):
    temp = aList[i]
    aList[i] = aList[j]
    aList[j] = temp

listToSort = [2, 5, 4]
selectionSort(listToSort)
print(listToSort)

listToSort = [5, 4, 2]
selectionSort(listToSort)
print(listToSort)

listToSort = []
selectionSort(listToSort)
print(listToSort)
```

Segundo algoritmo:

```
def selectionSort(listToSort):
    for i in range(0, len(listToSort) - 1):
        min = listToSort[i]
        posicao_min = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(listToSort)):
            if listToSort[j] < min:
                min = listToSort[j]
                posicao_min = j
        swap(listToSort, i, posicao_min)
    return listToSort

def swap(list, i, j):
    aux = list[i]
    list[i] = list[j]
    list[j] = aux

print(selectionSort([2, 5, 4]))
print(selectionSort([5, 4, 2]))
print(selectionSort([]))
```

Saída de ambos:

```
[2, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[]
```

Comment: Não entendi o sentido de "melhor" na pergunta. Por quê você acha que a primeira implementação é "melhor" que a sua?

Comment: @Gomiero o código é mais bem-distribuído entre as funções, e cada uma é responsável por uma atividade bem-definida que juntando cumpre o que o algoritmo propõe. Por isso também uso o termo modularizada  com um sentido de separação de conceitos/preocupações. Por fim, também acho melhor porque para terem-na projetado assim parece ter havido algum tipo de _insight_ que me faltou. Tivesse eu _"inlined"_ o `swap()`, aí sim teria ficado um "linguição" só (o que, no caso de um algoritmo mais extenso, poderia ser prejudicial para o entendimento e a manutenção).

Comment: Entendi! Acho que por causa do algoritmo da pergunta ser ordenação, onde o objetivo é desempenho (e a sua implementação é bem melhor!), o "melhor" gerou a dúvida. Os comentários da pergunta relacionada fazem sentido. É difícil definir "melhor", pois depende do tipo de sistema, do objetivo final, opiniões pessoais da equipe e vários outros fatores. IMO, não há uma "receita" perfeita. A resposta para a pergunta deve ser definida pelo time de desenvolvimento e individualizada para cada situação. Mas é apenas minha opinião, e se alguém responder com um bom argumento, vai me ajudar muito :-)